# Is there a way to ask the user before loading the website

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-website

I have recently been putting together a website which is incredibly content heavy, and I am wanting to prepare it for mobile viewing. However, one thing I am concerned about is that if the user decides to view the page while not connected to a WiFi network the website will destroy their mobile data plan.

What I was thinking then was to create a pop up message before any content is loaded asking the user if they would like to continue loading the website, and if they choose not to, to close the website. The pop up does not need to happen when the user is on a desktop, as they are more likely to be connected to a WiFi network.

Is this a good idea, and is it possible? Are there better methods? Or is this something that I should not be concerned about?

I only really know how to use Javascript, so if the solution is Javascript related, then that'd be perfect. However if it requires something else, please let me know.

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive with *why* the site is so data-intensive? How much data are you actually transferring per-page? You should re-consider your design as it relates to mobile and leverage some modern features of HTML and JS to decrease the load on mobile clients.

Comment: Surely a better idea would be to deliver a much "lighter" version of the site for mobile, by default. You haven't said what you mean by "heavy" exactly (what volume of data it is, or what that data consists of) or whether the large items are absolutely essential for the site to make sense. Perhaps you could load a smaller number of them or something. Designing for mobile requires a different approach anyway due to screen size, so you should already be planning a cut-down, responsive view of your site. We'd need a lot more details though to be able to suggest specific improvements.

Comment: If you do this popup, what you're basically saying to the user is "this site is horrible, you don't want to use it". Users are impatient, especially on mobile. If they don't like what they see, or you bug them with questions before they can get to what they are interested in, or your site takes too long to load, etc etc they'll move on - fast. Aim to deliver an optimised, small, hassle-free experience while still conveying the essential parts of whatever information it is you're trying to convey.

Comment: Initial content loads just pop-up, then you re-submit page to proper endpoint with full or minimal content

Comment: @ADyson By heavy content, I am referring to about having a lot of images (about 50, some of which are a couple MB large) as well as a few videos. It is a digital design portfolio website, so I would say that all of the graphics are important.

Comment: well then you should consider showing fewer images - 50 is far too many on a mobile page anyway really, people will be scrolling for ages unless you make them tiny. You could always have a "load more" option for people who really want to see the rest.

Comment: And consider serving compressed versions of them - you probably won't notice any difference in the display on a small screen anyway. The videos won't actually get downloaded unless the user chooses to play them, so that's less of a problem. You need to re-think the whole concept of what you're delivering, to suit the different display medium. If you're into digital design, then hopefully that's right up your street...

Comment: Use **srcset** for the images (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images), **lazyload** them (https://www.sitepoint.com/five-techniques-lazy-load-images-website-performance/), and put your site on a server (or use a CDN) that uses WebP compression (or something like that). 50 images is not **heavy-duty**, even if they are large. If you prepare your site for this, then (I think) it won't cause a problem, and you won't need any interstitial to stop/bounce your visitors. (Of course, I may be wrong about this ;) )

Comment: Alright, thank you for the information. I'm really new at the game; still studying in fact. And I'm still trying to get the hang of mobile-first design. I'll go and do more research. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put this in the first line of your javascript code

```js
let close = confirm("This website is data heavy, if you have a limited data plan click OK") == true ? window.top.close() : "Do nothing";
```

It simply asks the user to confirm that they want to continue and the ternary statement checks if they said no and if they did it closes that tab.